# How to configure caching for static resources in Sitecore

Tags: configuration, caching

How can I enable caching for static resources such as CSS and JavaScript files in a Sitecore solution? I need these resources to have the following response header present:

```
Cache-Control:public, max-age=14400
```

I have the following settings in web.config with no success.

## #1 system.webServer/caching

This breaks Sitecore completely. Returns 500 response code with no error information.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <caching enabled="true" enableKernelCache="true">
      <profiles>
        <add extension=".js" policy="CacheForTimePeriod" duration="365.00:00:00"/>
      </profiles>
    </caching>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

## #2 system.webServer/staticContent/clientCache

This makes no change to the response headers.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00"/>
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

## #3 location/system.webServer/staticContent/clientCache

This also makes no change to the response headers.

```
<configuration>
  <location path="themes">
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="00:00:15" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hmm, are you sure the last one doesn't work?
We have a web.config in our static content folder, containing:
  <staticContent>
   <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30:00:00" />
  </staticContent>
and it returns the correct headers for files in this folder:
Cache-Control: max-age=108000
Content-Length: 212946
Content-Type: application/x-javascript
Last-Modified: Mon, 24 Apr 2017 19:00:52 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "0caf0172dbdd21:0"

Comment: @ChrisvandeSteeg I tried what you suggested but it doesn't seem to make any difference. I created a web.config in the themes folder with the following content: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="30:00:00" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  
</configuration>`

Comment: Can you please confirm that your using IIS (and not IIS Express) and which version.

Comment: @RichardHauer using regular IIS version 10 (running in Windows 10).

Comment: What's the value of the cache-control header you are getting? In the "HTTP Response Headers" section of your site in IIS, do you have a "Cache-Control" custom header? BTW forget about that first snippet, the duration is too long and anyway it appends a no-cache directive.

Comment: @maz I _was_ getting nothing, but it seems this was a stupid mistake on my part. The files were being, err cached, by the browser. Doing a hard refresh showed the correct response headers.

Comment: @MatthewDresser that was the next thing I was going to ask you. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Option #3 actually ***does*** work. I forgot to do a hard refresh in my browser during testing. Oops.

So you can add this to your main web.config

```
<configuration>
  <location path="themes">
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Or if you prefer, you can create a new web.config in the `themes` folder with the following content which achieves the same thing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

## When testing caching settings, don't forget to do a hard refresh!

Comment: You should go back and retry #2 as well.  If #3 works, chances are #2 will also.

Comment: How-to hard refresh ?

Comment: @Kiquenet [Ctrl] + [Shift] + [R] in chrome

Comment: If a hard refresh is necessary to verify that this caching fix works, then by definition, it doesn't work.